# Object's height not a multiple of layer height

Tags: slicing, dimensional-accuracy

This basic question has been bothering me for a while.

Let's say I'm printing an object of height 20.1 mm with 0.2 mm layers. What will the slicer do? in other words, how will it print the last layer? Since I'm printing with 0.2 mm layers, my object will be printed in 11 layers, but the last one would make my object 20.2 mm high. Is there some sort of compensation (in Slic3r or Cura for example), or will I just get an inaccurate object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slicers will round off to the next nearest layer, so 20.2 mm in your case. However, you can get to 20.1 mm if you use a 0.3 mm first layer.

Comment: Might want to add that the ultimate layer height may vary depending on material, print temperature, etc, so it depends a bit on how many sig figs of accuracy the OP needs in his final part.